# Monit starts multiple instances of the process

Tags: linux

We are facing a problem in Arch Linux with monit where multiple instances of the process are getting instantiated.

The script is:
*check process checkprogram 
    matching checkprogram

```
start program = "/usr/bin/check/checkprogram" as uid localuser
stop program  = "/bin/bash /usr/bin/scripts/killprocess.sh checkprogram"
```

if 3 restarts within 20 cycles then stop*

killprocess.sh contains the following script:

```
*kill $(ps -C "$1" -o pid | grep [[:digit:]])*
```

When I see the monit log, it shows:

```
*[UTC Jul  5 17:53:32] error    : 'checkprogram' process is not running
[UTC Jul  5 17:53:32] info     : 'checkprogram' trying to restart
[UTC Jul  5 17:53:32] info     : 'checkprogram' start: /usr/bin/check/checkprogram
[UTC Jul  5 17:53:36] info     : 'checkprogram' process is running with pid 19344
[UTC Jul  6 06:55:01] error    : 'checkprogram' process PID changed from 19344 to 15773
[UTC Jul  6 06:55:01] error    : 'checkprogram' process PPID changed from 1 to 19344
[UTC Jul  6 06:55:05] error    : 'checkprogram' process PID changed from 15773 to 19344
[UTC Jul  6 06:55:05] error    : 'checkprogram' process PPID changed from 19344 to 1
[UTC Jul  6 06:55:09] info     : 'checkprogram' process PID has not changed since last cycle
[UTC Jul  6 06:55:09] info     : 'checkprogram' process PPID has not changed since last cycle
[UTC Jul  6 14:17:31] error    : 'checkprogram' process PID changed from 19344 to 14511
[UTC Jul  6 14:17:31] error    : 'checkprogram' process PPID changed from 1 to 19344
[UTC Jul  6 14:17:35] error    : 'checkprogram' process PID changed from 14511 to 19344
[UTC Jul  6 14:17:35] error    : 'checkprogram' process PPID changed from 19344 to 1
[UTC Jul  6 14:17:39] info     : 'checkprogram' process PID has not changed since last cycle
[UTC Jul  6 14:17:39] info     : 'checkprogram' process PPID has not changed since last cycle
[UTC Jul  7 00:28:26] error    : 'checkprogram' process PID changed from 19344 to 10938
[UTC Jul  7 00:28:26] error    : 'checkprogram' process PPID changed from 1 to 463
[UTC Jul  7 00:28:30] error    : 'checkprogram' process PID changed from 10938 to 19344
[UTC Jul  7 00:28:30] error    : 'checkprogram' process PPID changed from 463 to 1
[UTC Jul  7 00:28:34] info     : 'checkprogram' process PID has not changed since last cycle
[UTC Jul  7 00:28:34] info     : 'checkprogram' process PPID has not changed since last cycle
[UTC Jul  7 18:40:41] error    : 'checkprogram' process PID changed from 19344 to 10731
[UTC Jul  7 18:40:41] error    : 'checkprogram' process PPID changed from 1 to 463
[UTC Jul  7 18:40:45] error    : 'checkprogram' process PID changed from 10731 to 19344
[UTC Jul  7 18:40:45] error    : 'checkprogram' process PPID changed from 463 to 1
[UTC Jul  7 18:40:49] info     : 'checkprogram' process PID has not changed since last cycle
[UTC Jul  7 18:40:49] info     : 'checkprogram' process PPID has not changed since last cycle
[UTC Jul  8 07:46:43] error    : 'checkprogram' process is not running
[UTC Jul  8 07:46:43] info     : 'checkprogram' trying to restart
[UTC Jul  8 07:46:43] info     : 'checkprogram' start: /usr/bin/check/checkprogram
[UTC Jul  8 07:46:47] info     : 'checkprogram' process is running with pid 11517*
```

Does anyone have an idea why the multiple instances are being launched? Any tips to debug this issue are also welcome.

Regards,
ossk

Comment: It is probably related to evaluating the expression which determines if the process is running. Have you tried running the expression when one process is running to check the output you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for your response - can you expand further on "Have you tried running the expression when one process is running to check the output you are getting?"

Comment: Having a similar issue. Tried using procmatch instead of pid file checking, but no dice: Mmonit always launches the start program multiple times. Setting timeout did not help.